# Votes cast by week higher than by month

Tags: support, bug, voting

I was browsing through my profile and notice that my votes per week has a a higher number of votes cast than per month.

Is this a bug?

[image: SS]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack Overflow [starts each week on Sunday](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow) as evidenced by the reputation leagues.

[image: Start of week as evidenced by league]

This month (May 2017) starts on a Monday, so since we're in the first week of that month the current week is one day longer than the current month, hence the larger number.

So no, it's not a bug.